# Save PDF DataUri as pdf with jsPDF

Tags: javascript, pdf, jspdf, data-uri

Is it possible to create and save a PDF file from `dataUri-string` with `jsPDF`?
This is my saved string in the database:

```
var pdfAsDataUri = "data:application/pdf;base64,JVBERi0xLjUK...";
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The HTML5 **download** attribute allows you to specify the desidered filename.
This works only in some browsers.

http://caniuse.com/download

So instead of using

```
window.open("data:application/pdf;base64,JVBERi0xLjUK...");
```

you can create a download link:

```html
<a href="data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,HELLO!!!!" download="hello.txt">download</a>
```

To create your download link in javascript using the download attribute and downloading it directly:

```
var a=document.createElement('a');
a.download='FileName.pdf';
a.href=pdfAsDataUri;
a.click();
```

else, like i said

```
window.open(pdfAsDataUri);
```

but no filename can be specified.

---

Another solution is to use `php` and output the correct headers, a binary file and the filename.

As it's not clear which db you are using and where do you want to save the file,
btw, if i maybe didn't understand your question correctly and you want to store the pdf somewhere on the server than you need in any case some serverside programming language like `php`, `asp`, `nodejs` and many more.